# Why `sum(dices = [dice() for i in range(num_rolls)])` and `while k < n: sum += dice() k += 1` results are different?

Tags: python-3.x

```
def roll_dice(num_rolls, dice=six_sided):
    dices = [dice() for i in range(num_rolls)]
    if 1 in dices:
        return 1
    return sum(dices)


def roll_dice(num_rolls, dice=six_sided):
    s = 0
    n = 0
    while n < num_rolls:
        c = dice()
        if c == 1:
            return 1
        s += c
        n += 1
    return s
```

Error encounted:

```
>>> from hog import *
>>> counted_dice = make_test_dice(4, 1, 2, 6)
>>> roll_dice(3, counted_dice)
1
>>> roll_dice(1, counted_dice)
2

# Error: expected
#     6
# but got
#     2
```

```
def make_test_dice(*outcomes):
    assert len(outcomes) > 0, 'You must supply outcomes to make_test_dice'
    for o in outcomes:
        assert type(o) == int and o >= 1, 'Outcome is not a positive integer'
    index = len(outcomes) - 1
    def dice():
        nonlocal index
        index = (index + 1) % len(outcomes)
        return outcomes[index]
    return dice
>>> dice = make_test_dice(1, 2, 3)
>>> dice()
1
>>> dice()
2
>>> dice()
3
>>> dice()
1
>>> dice()
2
```

I don't understand what's going on here, why does the method of using s += c cause such an error, what is the difference between two methods?
I don't understand why the returned value here is 6, and I would like an explanation.

Comment: The question is a bit confusing, perhaps it would be better to change the names of the functions to `roll_dice1()` and `roll_dice2()` and show the tests individually. The two functions are significantly different. While the first version runs the `dice()` function `num_rolls` times before deciding whether to return 1 or a sum, the second version runs the `dice()` function each time it decides whether to return 1 or a sum, which means that the `dice()` function may not always be called `num_rolls` times.

Comment: A [trace table test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_table), or step-by-step debugging, applied simultaneously to both functions would show the difference in operation between them.

Answer (score 0):

There is much you haven't told us, but I can make a guess.

I'm going to ASSUME that `make_test_dice` uses something like `itertools.cycle` to return an iterable that cycles through the parameters.  One of the side effects is that it REMEMBERS where it left off.

When you get called with `roll_dice(3, dice)`, it expects you to consume 3 items, even if one of those is a 1.  Your second function doesn't do that.  It takes an early exit -- it stops as soon as it sees a 1.  Thus, you exit with the iterator pointing at the 2.  If you had consumed all 3 items, like the first function, then it would be left pointing at the 6.

Comment: It seems that it should be, when there is a value of 1, the second method will directly return and terminate the entire iteration to continue running. I didn't notice this.

Comment: No, it does not terminate the iteration.  That's the issue.  The `dice()` iterator has state.  It remembers.